# PerfMon plugin throwing error (with use of variables) in JMeter distributed Mode

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

I have implemented [PerfMon Metrics Collector](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) (listeners) in my JMeter scripts. These listeners have HOST and PORT fields. I have defined variables for these in Test Plan and using them in listeners.

I tested these scripts in non-distributed mode and it worked perfectly.

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Now, I converted my scripts for distributed mode. Everything works fine except PerfMon listeners which throw following error message:

> > 2016/02/29 09:06:35 ERROR - kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector: Perfmon plugin error: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine

This error seemed to be related to invalid value (may be these listeners do not handle special characters like {} $ in distributed mode!!). So, I removed variables for HOST/PORT and instead used hard coded values and it worked fine.

So apparently, these listeners do not work properly in distributed mode (IF used with variables).

Is there any workaround for this issue as I have plenty of PerfMon listeners in my setup and manually changing them all will be a tiresome job.

Answer (score 1):

Go for JMeter Properties instead of JMeter Variables, like:

- Substitute `${HOST}` with `${__P(HOST,)}`
- Substitute `${PORT}` with `${__P(PORT,)}`
- Pass `HOST` and `PORT` properties values on JMeter **master** side like:

  ```
  jmeter -GHOST=target_hostname_or_IP -GPORT=target_port -s -n -t ....
  ```
- You can have different values on different slaves, in that case specify properties in *user.properties* file (it's located under /bin folder of JMeter installation) like:

  ```
  HOST=10.20.30.40
  PORT=1234
  ```

  Remember to restart JMeter after editing any configuration file.

References:

- [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) documentation
- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for solution but i think it will only work if I run tests from command line !! Whereas currently, I am running my 'distributed tests' from JMeter GUI using 'Remote Start All' option. Do we have any similar option to run 'distributed mode tests' from command line?

Comment: Global properties are applied to all remote slaves